# В каком виде передать в график Highcharts свои данные для подписи оси x?

Tags: php, highcharts, диаграммы

Здравствуйте.

Есть график такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные по оси У подставляются без проблем.
Однако мне нужно внизу выводить соответствующие даты и я никак не могу сообразить, как это сделать.

Если передаю строку, то получается так, как на картинке.
Если передаю массив- почти тоже самое, просто даты через запятую без кавычек, однако они все находятся в одной ячейке.
И только вручную: '2017-00-00', '2017-01-01' - работает. (собственно поэтому и попробовала передавать именно строку, но это не помогло)

В чем секрет, может кто подскажет?

Answer (score 1):

создать массив дат, например days, и передать его в xAxis:

```
var days = ['1/1/2017', '11/2/2017', '1/3/2017', '4/4/2017', '5/4/2017', '6/5/2017','7/10/2017', '11/10/2017', '11/11/2017', '15/12/2017', '16/12/2017', '21/12/2017'];
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'spline'
},
title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: days
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature'
    },
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return this.value + '°';
        }
    }
},
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
    shared: true
},
plotOptions: {
    spline: {
        marker: {
            radius: 4,
            lineColor: '#666666',
            lineWidth: 1
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    marker: {
        symbol: 'square'
    },
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
        y: 26.5,
        marker: {
            symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
        }
    }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

}, {
    name: 'London',
    marker: {
        symbol: 'diamond'
    },
    data: [{
        y: 3.9,
        marker: {
            symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/snow.png)'
        }
    }, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
}]
});
```